# If cpu frequency scaling is not supported, server will run at max performance?

Tags: performance, cpu

```
SERVER413:~ # modprobe acpi_cpufreq
FATAL: Error inserting acpi_cpufreq (/lib/modules/3.0.101-108.13-default/kernel/drivers/cpufreq/acpi-cpufreq.ko): Input/output error
SERVER413:~ #
```

In the BIOS, all settings are on "Max performance".

However, we cannot check it from OS level:

```
SERVER413:~ # for i in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor; do cat $i; done
cat: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor: No such file or directory
SERVER413:~ #
```

We want the server to always run on "max" performance.

**Q:** Does this mean that the server will always run on max performance?

If CPU scaling would be supported, it would only downscale the CPU, no?

If we check, what MHz is it running, it is running at:

```
SERVER413:~ # grep -E '^cpu MHz' /proc/cpuinfo | sort -u
cpu MHz         : 2294.633
SERVER413:~ #
```

https://ark.intel.com/products/84683/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E7-8880-v3-45M-Cache-2_30-GHz

SLES 11.4. Although there is some "turbo frequency" mentioned on ark.intel with 3.1 GHz...

Comment: Maybe E5 Xeons doesn't support the scaling_governor? E7 Xeons looks ok, but cannot find any diff in documentations about scaling governor..